Secure and efficient way to have remote desktop of cloud GPU running Linux
Currently I have rented a cloud GPU (Nvidia L4) w/ 25vCPUs and 100GBvRAM. I was hoping to run LMstudio on it, but would like the UI to be visible on my PC. Wondering if exporting DISPLAY to treat LMstudio UI as an XWindows applicstion, running XWindows server on my local PC (which doesn't have a decent discrete GPU), running Ubuntu Linux, is indeed a secure way ? Or should I setup something like tightVNC ?

Have you tried either of those methods to verify they are even an option? You’re currently limiting yourself to individuals with a Nividia cloud VM. I would be willing to research the subject but I am not entirely sure what Nividia service your referring to.

My research indicates you can connect to these VMs through VMWare and Citrix products
